# Jira API Created New fixVerisons value

Tags: python, jira-rest-api

Trying to use the JIRA api to set/add the fixVersions field but I'm running into an error if the fixVersions value has not been created.   I've tried set and add I get the following error response.  Note I am able to create a new fixVersions via the UI but would like to do this via the api.

{"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"fixVersions":"Version name '1.0.0.1' is not valid"}}

Here is my sample python that is working if the fixVersion exists.

```
   import requests
   import json

   header = {'content-type': 'application/json','charset':'utf-8'}
   # add works if the fixVersion exists
   #payload = {"update":{"fixVersions":[{"add":{"name":"1.0.0.0"}}]}}

   payload = {"update": {"fixVersions" : [{"set":[{"name":"1.0.0.1"}]}]}}

   url = 'https://domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue/BLAH-1111'

   r = requests.put(url,headers=header,json=payload,auth=('user', 'pass'))

   print r.status_code
   print r.reason
   print r.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the API for adding versions under /rest/api/2/version

```
import requests
import json

header = {'content-type': 'application/json','charset':'utf-8'}

payload = {"description": "1.0.0.1 version",
    "name": "1.0.0.1",
    "archived": False,
    "released": False,
    "releaseDate": "2016-01-29",
    "project": "BLAH",
    "projectId": 100
    }

url = 'https://domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/version'

r = requests.post(url,json=payload,headers=header,auth=('user', 'pass'))

print r.status_code
print r.reason
print r.text
```

Comment: It works. That helps me to create a new fix version.